# How do I add my domain to the whitelist?

Tags: flash, facebook-sharer

re: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

According to the documentation outlining the facebook sharer.php, in order to post flash inline I need to add my domain to the facebook whitelist. However, I can find no information detailing the procedure to accomplish this.

Perhaps you can help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is necessary anymore.  There is a link to contact them on that page but it is dead.  You should just user the [open graph video meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and as long as it is an .swf file it should be fine.  If that still doesn't work, contact them [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).